# Assembly 8051 Multiplying unsigned 2-byte numbers by 1-byte numbers

Tags: assembly, 8051

I'm dealing with the assembler task from school. We got 3 programs and this is one of them. i'm trying to answear questions, but it would be way easier by knowning anything about assembler before (no matter how nonsense it sounds, our teacher really didn't teach us anything).

Given that the 2-byte number contains of 3 (lsb) and 4(msb):

1. How will the number look like?
2. What will the result look like from multiplying the resulted number and number 16? (what will be the final answear of the program really)

It would be such easier to understand how the multiplication is working really, because I have to project the final value as 24-bit number.

```
1 ;main.s03
2
3 name MAIN
4 extern _R,MUL21
5 rseg CODE
6 mov PSW,#_R
7 mov SP,#BSTACK-1
8
9 mov R0,#3 ;number 1, lsb
10 mov R1,#4 ; msb
11 mov R2,#16 ;number 2
12 lcall MUL21 ;result R6,R5,R4
13
14 sjmp $
15
16 rseg ISTACK
17 BSTACK: ds 8
18
19 end
```

```
1 ;mul21.s03
2
3 name MUL21
4 extern _R
5 public MUL21
6 rseg CODE
7 MUL21: mov A,R0
8 mov B,R2
9 mul AB
10 mov R4,A
11 mov R5,B ;R5,R4=R0*R2
12
13 mov A,R1
14 mov B,R2
15 mul AB
16 add A,R5
17 mov R5,A
18 mov A,B
19 addc A,#0
20 mov R6,A ;R6,R5+=R1*R2,R4
21
22 ret
23
24 end
```

1. My guess is 43
2. Shouldn't it be 43 * 16?

Comment: Your msb is x256 so the 16 bit number should be 4*256 + 3 = 1027. If you then multiply by 16, that gives 1027*16 = 16432. I don't know the assembler you're using but multiplying by 16 is usually done by bit shifting left four bits rather than multiplying.

Comment: The code itself has been given to us, I did not write it in any way. We are operating on the DOSbox with Intel's 8051.
Thank you for your explainantion.
If my msb is x256, and the 2-byte number itself is 1027, how will the numerical sub-results for lines 7:11 look like in the subprogram mul21?

Comment: Don't guess.  Reason it out.  Follow each instruction to see what it's effect on the program state is (A & B registers & global variables Rn).  Most of the instructions are simple, just copying an 8-bit value from one place to another.  Keep a scratchpad of the latest values at each location, and update it for each instruction.

Comment: The 8051 `mul AB` instruction does 8-bit × 8-bit yielding a 16-bit result with low 8 bits of that in A, and high 8 bits in B.

Comment: Sure, but I need to make myself sure on one more thing: if in the line 15 there is multiplying the msb number with the 16 number - would the "A" here be a (4*256) or just 4? It should be 4*256 then, as it's the msb, right?

Comment: Start at line 13: `mov A, R1` for that one — what value is in R1?  Don't worry about "MSB" and "LSB", but instead focus on the actual numeric 8-bit values being used.

Comment: So we should be loading the R1 value of 4 to the A. Then doing the same with the R2 value of 16 to the B. Multiplying should leave us with the number 64. This value should be registered in the A

Comment: Yes, keep going

Comment: We need to add the valure from R5 to the A, which we should get from the previous lines: load 3 to A, 16 to B; multiply them to get the 48, where 48 would stay in the A, 0 in the B. A will get loaded to R4 and B to R5, so coming back to the line 16: We are adding 0 to the current A, which gives 64 + 0 = 64. We are loading this A value to R5 and the B, which would be 0 to the A, which gives us 0 in both A and B now. In the line 19 I only know that we are adding the carry flag of 0 to the A and in the end writting down the A to R6. This is clearly wrong, but I don't know where

Comment: I believe you have it right.  You should see 0x30 aka 48 in R4, and 0x40 aka 64 in R5, while R6 has 0.  Now look at the number stored in R6, R5, R4 as a 24-bit number; it is 0x 00 40 30, which has decimal value 16432.

Comment: FYI, the `add` instruction line 16, sets the carry flag to 1 or 0 depending on if there's an 8-bit unsigned carry or not, but here there isn't so it set the carry flag to 0.  The `addc` will add to A both the immediate (#0) and the 0-valued carry.

Comment: There's understanding the machine code and what each instruction does, which I think you have now, and then understanding the algorithm and how it works.  To see the result as valid, remember to look at the inputs 0x03 and 0x04 as one two-byte value 0x0403, which is 1027, and it is later multiplied by 16.  I use hex as it helps make it clear how these two one-byte values compose into one two-byte value.  Same for the final result.

Comment: Btw, +1 for working through this yourself.

Comment: Well, if we got the values R4 = 48, R5 = 64, R6 = 0, so would it be 00110000 01000000 00000000?

Comment: Oh okay, so you had edited it before I read it and responded. Thank you so much for help. Definitely looking at it as hex values helps a lot.
It is really a shame that creating a ticket here is way more educational than my university classes

Comment: Happy to help an engaged learner.  FYI, hex is just a way of composing numbers using base 16 instead of base 10; hex allows for simple combinations of binary digits, though the same values could be written in decimal entirely, as an expression, i.e. 4 * 256^1 + 3 * 256^0 = 0x0403 = 1027 and also 00 * 256^2 + 64 * 256^1 + 48 * 256 ^ 0...

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] to learn what this site is all about, for example, it is not a forum. Anyway, @Erik and you did a good job in _your_ learning. -- However, to make this question valuable for others, please write an actual answer, if you feel that it is worth to be kept. Else please remove it, so that it does not mislead future visitors like me. They do not expect answers in comments.

Comment: @ErikEidt Sorry for bothering you, but I talked to HaxerOne. English is not my native language, I apologize for not being understandable. -- This site has far too many open questions, which mislead people like me, in the sense that I looked into it just to find that it is answered in comments. Since this is a reputation-based site, I don't want to receive points in place of some other member. So I see these two options and the responsibility at the OP to decide, at least as a learning step. -- Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: @thebusybee, my apologies, as I misread your comment..

Comment: thebusybee is ineed right - I wanted to mark one of your comments as the answear to complete the question, but due to them beeing comments - I cannot. If you would like to wrap this up @ErikEidt and post an answear to this, I would be happy to give you +1. If not, I hope you don't mind me posting a solution here and closing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow each instruction to see what it's effect on the program state is (A & B registers & global variables Rn).

Most of the instructions are simple, just copying an 8-bit value from one place to another.  Keep a scratchpad showing the latest values at each location/step in the machine code program, and update that scratchpad for each instruction.

The 8051 `mul AB` instruction does 8-bit × 8-bit yielding a 16-bit result with low 8 bits of that in A, and high 8 bits in B.

Don't worry about the algorithm for now (and terminology MSB, LSB), just concentrate on the 8-bit values and how they move / are generated by each instruction.

Kind of separately, we can look at the algorithm, and the input values and output value.  Hex is a good to use when larger values (16-bit and 24-bit) are split across 8-bit bytes (as two 4-bit hex digits is one complete byte — to do with decimal, need more math).  The input is LSB 0x03 and MSB 0x04, so the 16-bit value is 0x0403, which is 1027 (decimal).  The algorithm multiples both halves (LSB, MSB) by the 8-bit multiplier (here 16), and then adds them together along with a carry that should be propagated.  As you worked out, the final output is 3 bytes, in hex 0x00, 0x40, 0x30, or as 24-bit number, 0x004030, which is 16342 (decimal).  As you can see, 0x0403 multiplied by 16 (which is "10" in hex) is 0x4030.